# Simplest Inverter

Tags: schematics, inverter, education, circuit-theory, dc-ac

Theoretically, what is the simplest inverter circuit possible?

I mean, really basic. With the least amount of components. It doesn't have to be nice. It doesn't have to step up the voltage, or anything. All it has to do is convert DC →AC. Purely theoretical.

Comment: "All it has to do is convert DC →AC. " So an oscillator?

Comment: Ring is my favorite:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_oscillator
Colpitts oscillator is one of the most basic analog ones:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colpitts_oscillator

Answer (score 3):

Too easy:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2B1pr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just two components. You can see what they used to look like [here](https://www.amplifiedparts.com/products/vibrator-6-volt-4-pin-negative-ground). Those are now sold almost entirely as solid state re-designed devices. But that doesn't change the fact that they used to be merely a carefully weighted mechanical module with a coil. I still have a couple of them dating back to when I would replace them in car radios and HAM radios.

Here is a picture of one of them:

[image]

---

Somebody just reminded me of another approach:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffs3w7m.png)</sup>

Cheap garden light IC, there. So two parts, again. (Plus the usual supply voltage, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you mean oscillators, because that's what you're describing. I'm not assuming a 3 phase inverter because you're not implying that.

---

[image]

[Here's a 4-component one.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%201.2182493960703473%2034%205%2050%0Aw%20320%20224%20320%20288%200%0Aa%20176%20288%20320%20288%201%201%200%201000000%200%20-0.6318065514210729%0Al%20176%20224%20176%20272%200%200.001%20-0.6318065514210729%0Ac%20320%20224%20176%20224%200%200.00001%20-0.15326610634180626%0Ag%20176%20304%20176%20320%200%0Ar%20176%20272%20176%20304%200%201%0Aw%20320%20288%20384%20288%200%0Aw%20112%20224%20176%20224%200%0Ao%202%201%200%204363%2020%200.8%200%202%202%203%0Ao%206%201%200%204099%201.25%200.00009765625%201%202%206%203%0A) If you make the \$1 Ω\$ resistor smaller then the voltage across the inductor will go really high (I've tested this circuit, but with a proper driving stage, worked good).

So the wire sticking out on the left would be your AC output, the wire sticking out on the right would be a square wave in case you would need that. Right now I've set the output of the op-amp to be 0-1V, if you make it higher then just like reducing the size of the resistor, you will make the voltage across the inductor sky high.

You can make a tap onto the coil to throw away the resistor, but this way you're going to get a couple of hundred volts across the inductor, but then it will be 3 components and a safety hazard.

Edit: I just remembered, this one won't self oscillate, you will need to briefly touch the left wire with some voltage to get the oscillation going. It won't work like in the simulation where the op-amp has near infinite amplification. (I won't say infinite because it's being simulated with bits and bytes).

---

Here's another one that is simple, **I've just added components to make it unideal like in the real world**.

[image]

[All in all it's 6 resistors and 3 transistors.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%205.0000000000000004e-8%207.619785657297057%2050%205%2043%0Aw%20752%20336%20512%20336%200%0Aw%20992%20336%20752%20336%200%0Aw%201056%20432%201056%20544%200%0Aw%20992%20432%201056%20432%200%0Aw%20880%20448%20880%20464%200%0Aw%20992%20400%20992%20432%200%0Ar%20816%20448%20880%20448%200%206.5%0Af%20880%20448%20944%20448%200%201.5%200.02%0Ac%20880%20464%20880%20496%200%202.85e-10%202.657525516260463%0Ac%20992%20432%20992%20496%200%204.5e-11%200.2315251600868511%0Ag%20992%20496%20992%20512%200%0Ag%20880%20496%20880%20512%200%0Ar%20992%20432%20944%20432%200%200.065%0Ar%20992%20336%20992%20400%200%201000%0Ag%20944%20464%20944%20512%200%0Ag%20704%20464%20704%20512%200%0Ar%20752%20336%20752%20400%200%201000%0Ar%20752%20432%20704%20432%200%200.065%0Ag%20640%20496%20640%20512%200%0Ag%20752%20496%20752%20512%200%0Ac%20752%20432%20752%20496%200%204.5e-11%200.17956177562335082%0Ac%20640%20464%20640%20496%200%202.85e-10%203.0034461429980754%0Af%20640%20448%20704%20448%200%201.5%200.02%0Ar%20752%20432%20816%20432%200%2010000%0Ar%20576%20448%20640%20448%200%206.5%0Aw%20752%20400%20752%20432%200%0Aw%20640%20448%20640%20464%200%0Aw%20400%20448%20400%20464%200%0AR%20512%20336%20512%20304%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%201056%20544%20336%20544%200%0Aw%20512%20400%20512%20432%200%0Ar%20336%20448%20400%20448%200%206.5%0Ar%20512%20432%20576%20432%200%2010000%0Af%20400%20448%20464%20448%200%201.5%200.02%0Ac%20400%20464%20400%20496%200%202.85e-10%200.913949227829375%0Ac%20512%20432%20512%20496%200%204.5e-11%204.816164698993012%0Ag%20512%20496%20512%20512%200%0Ag%20400%20496%20400%20512%200%0Ar%20512%20432%20464%20432%200%200.065%0Ar%20512%20336%20512%20400%200%201000%0Ag%20464%20464%20464%20512%200%0Ar%20336%20448%20336%20544%200%2010000%0Aw%20816%20432%20816%20448%200%0Aw%20576%20432%20576%20448%200%0Aw%201056%20432%201104%20432%200%0Ao%203%208%200%204362%205%200.00625%200%202%203%203%0A) So the \$1kΩ\$ and \$10kΩ\$ are actual components, the other small capacitors and resistors are unideal components inside of the transistor. It's a type of ring inverter.

The reason for why I included this one, even though it has more components than the first one, is because perhaps you want something small, who knows, your question is vague. 
This circuit doesn't need an inductor, which makes it much smaller right off the bat. And inside of an op-amp there's several transistors, so saying that an op-amp is just one component is like cheating. Because then I could just use one component, a microcontroller and make it oscillate in software.

---

If you actually meant 3 phase inverter, then me and mkeith and probably many others have failed to understand you.

Comment: You could also use the classic 2 transistors, 2 capacitors, 4 resistors astable circuit, instead of a ring oscillator.

Comment: @next-hack I've tried that circuit and had very bad results with it. I don't know if it's low quality transistors or me being bad. I only got it to work by "band-aiding" the resistors. In other words I put more and more resistors in parallel until it worked. Apparently there was some sweet spot for the resistors. (The circuit worked when I had some particular resistor at 25kΩ, not 28kΩ and not 22kΩ). When I simulated the circuit it was not supposed to be sensitive to the values. - I've had 100% success with the ring oscillator in my answer.

Comment: That sound strange. I usually use a couple of BC547, and almost never had problems in a various range of frequencies... Of course, resistors and capacitor must help oscillation (and also its startup).

Comment: @next-hack I thought you meant [this one](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/electronics/multivibrator.jpg). I just realized that it has 6 resistors and a mosfet (not 4 resistors), BC547 is an NPN. I believe you're talking about the famous [astable multivibrator](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/tim20.gif).  Yeah that one I've had no problems with.

Comment: Yes, I meant that famous astable oscillator. I think (but actually I never tried) it could work with MOSFETs too (I will try with two BS170 this evening).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a classic relaxation oscillator circuit. Pretty simple.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f885yN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The same number of parts is also possible with a UJT circuit (eg 2N2646- not a PUT) or a neon lamp, and about as simple with a tunnel diode. None of those parts except perhaps the neon lamp is very popular these days.

Answer (score 0):

The DC powers the inverter. That is not shown in this picture. Note that a CMOS inverter may only contain two transistors (if it is not buffered). So this is not a complex circuit, even though it uses an IC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0B0Qn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I guess that NOT is actually a Schmitt trigger inverter (e.g. 74xx14).

Comment: Yeah. I just grabbed whatever. I guess there could be some danger that it may misbehave if you don't have hysteresis. Get stuck in the middle or something. I am pretty sure I did this once long ago to fix some problem with an I2C device that hung up the bus during reboot. The inverter oscillator clocked the I2C bus somehow during reset, and that fixed the problem. But it might have been a Schmitt trigger inverter.